# How to write .htaccess dynamically in wordpress?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to set permalink structure on theme activation. The following function included in function.php of theme.

```
// Executes function on theme activation
function myactivationfunction() {

    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%category%/%postname%/' );
    // register taxonomies/post types here
    flush_rewrite_rules();

}
add_action("after_switch_theme", "myactivationfunction", 10 ,  2);
```

This code works correctly but value not writing into .htaccess or .htaccess not creating. How can i write .htaccess file dynamically?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: check permissions for web server user

Comment: @gwillie  Everything is fine. Also checked this in localhost. But not working.

Comment: @gwillie The htaccess creating and site is functioning when i update permalink by clicking "Update" button from permalink settings. `flush_rewrite_rules();` not creating .htaccess file. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The flush has to run on `admin_init`, you call it inside the theme switch callback, so it'll run only once:

```
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'activate_so_19333403' );

function activate_so_19333403() {
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'flush_rewrites_so_19333403' );
}

function flush_rewrites_so_19333403() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/%category%/%postname%/' );
    flush_rewrite_rules();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not working. I think  `add_action( 'admin_init', 'flush_rewrites_so_19333403' );` not working in after_switch theme action. it working when i called it directly. How can i make it working?